# Difference between quick lime, slaked lime, lime water and soda lime

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

The chemicals "quick lime", "slaked lime", "lime water" and "soda lime" all have "lime" in common. What is the difference between them?

Comment: Aha, I wondered if this would be a self-answer -- most or all of this is on Wikipedia.

Comment: 'Milk of lime' is somewhat similar to limewater. It is the suspension of slaked lime in water whereas limewater is a true solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quick lime is calcium oxide, $\ce{CaO}$, in the solid state.

Slaked lime is calcium hydroxide, $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$, in the solid state.

Lime water is a dilute solution of calcium hydroxide, $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$, in water.

Soda lime is a mixture of sodium hydroxide, $\ce{NaOH}$, (also known as caustic soda) and calcium oxide, $\ce{CaO}$, (also known as quicklime).

Comment: Thanks for posting this! Can you add links to Wikipedia or elsewhere? Most of these are on Wik.

Comment: @hBy2Py, I did not refer to wikipedia. I knew this.

Comment: You may know these things, but including links to outside sources increases the usefulness of your answer to others.

Comment: Slaked lime comes from the idea of slaking the "thirst" of quick ("live" or "active") lime with water. Sort of an alchemical etymology.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the family of materials in the 'lime' category: The sedimentary rock [*limestone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limestone) is composed of [calcium carbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_carbonate), $\ce{CaCO3}$.

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia:

> [Quick lime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_oxide) is $\ce{CaO}$ (calcium oxide)
>   [Slaked lime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_hydroxide) is $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ (calcium hydroxide)
>   [Lime water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limewater) is just a dilute solution of calcium hydroxide.
>   [Soda lime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soda_lime) is a mixture of about 75% calcium hydroxide, a few percent each of sodium hydroxide and potassium hydroxide, and about 20% water.  It is commonly used to adsorb $\ce{CO2}$ from the air.

Comment: Soda lime works great for adsorbing other acidic gases, too: $\ce{NO2}$, $\ce{SO3}$, etc. I used it in my grad work for $\ce{NO2}$.

Answer (score 2):

I completely understand your frustration as all those names are trivial names (non-systematic.)

The "lime" is derived from the use of Limestone
https://www.etymonline.com/word/lime

I would have to mention that even those names are associated with chemical names that are not pure and contain some impurities.

**Lime** = **quicklime** ($\ce{CaO}$ - Calcium oxide) is made from **limestone** ($\ce{CaCO3}$ - Calcium carbonate) by decarbonisation at high temperatures.

To get **slaked lime** = hydrated lime ($\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ - Calcium hydroxide) you mix Lime with water, resulting in a white powdery substance.

In another process, you can make **lime water** - where you add lime into a greater amount of water resulting in water solution/suspension of hydrated lime
$\ce{Ca(OH)2}$  in water - this is also called **milk of lime**.